# AngularJS value is true and false at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have two divs. They should never be shown together at the same time. So I did this:

```
<div class="house" ng-if="$ctrl.house">my house</div>
<div class="no-house" ng-if="!$ctrl.house">homeless</div>
```

For a brief period of time though my app shows both `my house` and `homeless`. This makes the whole screen flash larger and makes all my graphs and other things jump around for half a second. It happens when `$ctrl.house` changes from `undefined` to an object `{}`.

My question here is how is this possible? I have one that says if true and the other that says if not true.

I even tried switching it to an ng-switch, but that had the same issue.

Comment: maybe not very clean but what about haviing something like ` <div ng-class="$ctrl.house? 'house': 'no-house'">{{$ctrl.house? "my house": "homeless"}}</div>
</div>`

Comment: I simplified this drastically. Inside the `my house` is actually another 30 nested tags and nested 2 components

Comment: @SamuelThompson this looks strange, what if you just print `{{$ctrl.house}}` on page? What do it print there? Are there any console errors?

Comment: @PankajParkar That kinda doesnt work because `{{$ctrl.house}}` is an object. but to simplify what you are saying it will show as `[object object]`. The only reason I am able to even see the false and true is because I freeze the code at the spot where I read the height of the tag. In that instance both are shown. upon unfreezing the script the incorrect ng-if will disappear. the problem is that this bug appears only for a few milliseconds and in that time the height is measured.

Comment: `{{ $ctrl.housr | json }}` shall print original object